# user is a specified mount option in fstab for a certain drive. But from a shell script, it wants superuser permission

Tags: bash

I fixed it. It wasn't mounting because of a mount option in `/etc/fstab` it was the `logdev=` option for xfs with an external log. I specified it using `logdev=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid of partition>` It wants the actual device node, ie `/dev/sda2`

The corrected script is below.

```
#Mount Debian mirror

if 
(( $(mount | grep -c mirror) == 0 )) && [ "$1" == "-m" ];
then
/bin/mount /home/tomas/mirror && echo "mirror has been mounted."
exit 0
elif
[ "$1" == "-m" ];
then 
echo "Mirror is already mounted."
exit 0
fi

if 
(( $(mount | grep -c mirror) == 1 )) && [ "$1" == "-u" ];
then 
sudo /bin/umount /home/tomas/mirror && echo "Umounting mirror."
exit 0
elif
[ "$1" == "-u" ] 
then
echo "Mirror is not mounted."
else
echo "Specify -m for mount or -u for umount."
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: In my case if I have the `user` option for mounting, I can mount and unmount without superuser permissions.
About *I know it is because the shell environment given to the script is not a user.* I don't understand what you meant. The shell  you are using for your script is `bash` (#!/bin/bash) and when you mount from the prompt you are also using `bash` (*It works for user mount from the bash prompt.*) and therefore both should work without any problem.

Comment: I tried your script and for mounting works without superuser perms. But you have logic errors. Your second `if` will never be executed because if the first `if` is false will run the code: `else echo "Mirror is already mounted."`
Can you add to your question the output of `cat /etc/fstab`?